# VS Code move Cache location in Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to use models from Hugging Face, but VS code always downloads them into my very limited `C:` drive; `C:\Users\<user>\.cache`.

How can I force it to cache to a different drive?

Things I've tried:

1. Googling: only seen threads for Linux, whose commands do not transfer over. Could not find clear equivalent commands for Windows.
2. Running a new instance from terminal `code --user-data-dir E:/.cache`
3. Fully un-installing VS Code, downloading a portable version, and making a `data` folder (following [these instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable))

All of them still result in caching to `C:\Users\<user>\.cache`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From some further research, it appears this is currently not possible.

However, I've found that symlinks is a great temporary workaround. In short,

1. Create a folder on a drive/partition with an abundance of space, i.e. `E:\TempCache`
2. Close any instances of VS Code, if any.
3. Navigate to `C:\Users\<username>\.cache`. If there's anything in it, cut them over to `E:\TempCache`, and delete the whole `.cache` folder.
4. Open cmd with admin rights, and enter `mklink /J "C:\Users\<name>\.cache" "E:\TempCache"`. This will re-create an empty `.cache` folder.

Next time VS Code is ran, it will automatically detect and use the `.cache` folder on the `C` drive like nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 11 Visual Studio Code will save its cached data under these two locations:

- %UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Code\Cache
- %UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Code\CachedData

I moved the whole ...\Code... folder and created a link (directory junction) with the following two commands.

```
move "%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Code" "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Code"

mklink /J "%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Code" "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Code"
```

There are also open issues for this.

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/148489 (closed duplicate)
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3884